# GWT: Getting a Reference to a DockLayoutPanel from a MenuBar

Tags: gwt

I am a newbie trying to use a MenuBar to swap the displayed panel in a DeckPanel.

I have 2 classes and 2 associated uibinder XML files:

- ApplicationUi.java
- ApplicationUi.ui.xml
- ApplicationMenu.java
- ApplicationMenu.ui.xml

In ApplicationUi.java and the UI XML, the root is bound to a DockLayoutPanel. The ApplicationMenu is meant to be in the North section of the DockLayoutPanel. The MenuBar options will affect the DeckPanel in the Center section.

In ApplicationMenu, how can I get a reference to the DeckPanel so I can call showWidget() to swap the displayed panel?

Also, since I'm a newb, any suggestions or reviews of this code are welcome. I've done the best I can on Google, but alot of what I'm looking for doesn't seem to be out there.

(This is a followup to [Replace GWT DockLayoutPanel Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901938/replace-gwt-docklayoutpanel-contents)).

Source:
ApplicationUi.java

```
import org.jason.datacenter.client.forms.NewRequirementForm;

public class ApplicationUi extends Composite {

private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, ApplicationUi> {
}

@UiField DockLayoutPanel dlp;
@UiField VerticalSplitPanel headerPanel;
@UiField DeckPanel deckPanel;

public ApplicationUi() {
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));

    // add the NewRequirementForm to the deckpanel as index #0
    deckPanel.add(new NewRequirementForm());
}

public void switchDeck(int newIndex) {
    deckPanel.showWidget(newIndex);
}
}
```

ApplicationUi.ui.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<ui:style>
    .panel {
        background-color: ivory;
    }
</ui:style>


<g:DockLayoutPanel ui:field="dlp">
    <g:north size="800">
        <g:VerticalSplitPanel ui:field="headerPanel">

        </g:VerticalSplitPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:center>
        <g:DeckPanel ui:field="deckPanel" />
    </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

ApplicationMenu.java:

```
public class ApplicationMenu extends Composite {

private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, ApplicationMenu> {
}

@UiField MenuBar applicationMenu;
@UiField MenuItem mitmNewPower;

public ApplicationMenu() {
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));

    mitmNewPower.setCommand(new Command() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            RootLayoutPanel rlp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
            DockLayoutPanel dlp = (DockLayoutPanel) rlp.getWidget(0);

        }
    });
}
```

}

ApplicationMenu.ui.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<ui:style>
    .panel {
        background-color: ivory;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:MenuBar ui:field="applicationMenu">
    <g:MenuItem>
        Process
        <g:MenuBar>
            <g:MenuItem ui:field="mitmNewPower" />
        </g:MenuBar>
    </g:MenuItem>

</g:MenuBar>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: I wrote a long answer on using MVP with GWT a while back, and using some of the ideas in it could help you achieve what you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832779/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-use-the-observer-pattern-in-mvp-using-gwt/2832919#2832919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to use an [EventBus](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html).  Create an event type and have your `ApplicationMenu` fire an event of that type when a menu item gets clicked.  The `ApplicationUi` object can subscribe to that event and respond to it by updating the contents of the `DeckPanel`.  This avoids the menu object needing to know about the `DeckPanel` at all.